# Why error "numerical expression has 50000 elements: only the first used" emerges in R?

Tags: r, hierarchical-data, mixed-models, weighted

I am fitting a null 4 level hlm model with sampling weights on all levels. I get an error that "numerical expression has 50000 elements: only the first used" 6 times and then the model runs. It produces not full output.

The data is in dataframe format with all of the columns being numerical values. There are no missing values.

```
library(WeMix)

model1 <- mix(result ~ 1 + (1|IDCNTRY:IDSCHOOL:IDCLASS) + 
           (1|IDCNTRY:IDSCHOOL) + (1|IDCNTRY), data=data, 
           weights=c("wgtst", "wgtcl", "wgtsch", "wgtcn"))`
```

Any help in solving this error would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Anonymus! Questions on SO (especially in R) do much better if they are reproducible and self-contained. By that I mean including attempted code (you have a good start here), sample representative data (perhaps via `dput(head(x))` or building data programmatically (e.g., `data.frame(...)`), possibly stochastically), perhaps actual output (with verbatim errors/warnings) versus intended output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.